# Are there standard comments for reviews?

Tags: discussion, review

I just reviewed [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/83007/configuring-proxy-settings-for-google-chrome-on-linux/775841#775841).

I downvoted and entered the following comment:

> Welcome to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)!  Please read through the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/tour) for information on how to both ask and answer questions.  I downvoted this answer because it is not an answer to the question that was originally asked.  You should instead [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) with your specific situation and details.  Thanks for your interest and participation!

Was this good?  What should be linked to & what should we normally say?  Is there a list of standard things to comment that you can point me to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that comment was good. There's no standard list of comments but the [proforma userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) a set of good comments, based on [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy)

Comment: +1 - Thanks Sathya.  I installed the Chrome plug-in and am able to access the comments popup via the `auto` link next to comment boxes.